# Manually set items transferred with a train

Tags: openttd

I have train that runs between a farm and a factory; it has 1 livestock cart, 4 grain carts and 2 goods carts. I want it to deliver livestock and grain from the farm to the factory, then collect goods and deliver it back to the farm.

At the station closest to the farm is a lorry station, a lorry should transport the goods into town.

The problem is that when the train reaches the farm it unloads the goods and then re-loads them immediately.

How can I set the train's behaviour to match the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the orders window for the train, and then click on the order telling it to go to the station. Somewhere under the orders list on the right, you should see a dropdown menu which is labeled "Unload All" (as seen in the image below). Select "Transfer" in the menu. This should make the train unload its cargo into the station and then leave empty.

[image: The vehicle orders menu]